# How can I prevent site search powered by a custom Google search engine from showing ads?

Tags: advertising, google-programmable-search-engine

I just set up this cse.google.com thing and it works great.

How can I prevent it from showing ads? I looked almost everywhere in the admin panel of cse.google.com but can't find anything related.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're signed up to the [FREE Google Custom Search Engine](https://cse.google.com/cse/), then unless you are registered as a qualifying nonprofit (incl. school or government agency) then I don't believe you can disable ads.

However, if you are registered as a nonprofit, then...

> To disable ads on a qualifying non-profit search engine:
>
> 1. From the Control Panel, select the search engine you want to change.
> 2. Click Setup then Make Money
> 3. Toggle the Show Ads option to off.

Reference:

- [Google CSE - Information for non-profits](https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/4542102?hl=en&ref_topic=4513746)

Comment: Google used to have a ad-free version of custom search called "Google Site Search " (GSS) that you could pay for.   However, they discontinued it.  Their [migration guide](https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/7669707?hl=en) says exactly what your answer says: Only non-profits, schools, and governments can remove the ads on Google Custom Search.